# How do I filter incoming connections based on server hostname/port using iptables?

Tags: linux, mysql, iptables

I have a couple of subdomains. Let's assume:

```
a.domain.com
b.domain.com
mysql.domain.com
c.domain.com
```

all pointing to the same IP address. I want to block all connections to port 3306, unless they want to connect to `mysql.domain.com`.

So something like:

```
mysql -h a.domain.com -P 3306 -u username
mysql -h b.domain.com -P 3306 -u username
```

should not be possible, but

```
mysql -h mysql.domain.com -P 3306 -u username
```

should work.

Is this possible using iptables? Or I have to do something else?

Comment: By the way, Siddhant, local etiquette is that after a reasonable
time you accept the best answer for any question you have asked, by clicking on the "tick" outline next to that answer.  That helps drive SF's reputation system both for you and the author of the accepted answer.  I mention this not so much in the context of this question as in your other one, which has several candidate answers.

Comment: Thanks for reminding. I just marked one as the best answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible, full stop.  `mysql`, like nearly all network-aware clients, does the DNS resolution at the client end, so the server never knows what lookup was performed to get the IP address that was then accessed.

There are, as you are aware, a very few services where the full server name is passed to the server as part of the protocol - HTTP springs to mind, and HTTPS using SNI - but these are the exception rather than the rule.